# Mirror local directory to Google Docs

Tags: sync, google-docs

I would like to use Google Docs to backup certain directories on my local machine. Trying to do this manual however is quite tedious as I have to keep track of which files have already been uploaded.

A full sync of certain directories à la Dropbox would be great, but this is more complicated and so far requires a commercial service like Syncplicity. A simple script that could be scheduled to upload 'new' files would roughly do what I want.

Does such an app/script already exist for the Windows platform?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CyberDuck (on OS X and 'dows) supports Google Docs as a target, but I don't know if it has any automation features.